# ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: angular, typescript

After pressing the button from the drop-down list:
         edition

the following error message appears in the console:

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/http/esm5/http.js.Body.json (http.js:1091)
    at MapSubscriber.project (user.service.ts:30)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1591)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

the error causes the method: **getUser** from the class: **UserService**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  public jwtToken: string;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    const theUser: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (theUser) {
      this.jwtToken = theUser.token;
    }
  }

  getUser(userid) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', `${this.jwtToken}`);
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(`/user/${userid}`, options)
      .map((response: Response) =>  response.json()  );
  }
}
```

class code **src/app/user/user-edition/user-edition.component.ts** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-edition',
  templateUrl: './user-edition.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-edition.component.css']
})
export class UserEditionComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;
  UserType = UserType;
  userObj: any;
  profileForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private userService: UserService,
              private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService) {}

  username  = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  password  = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  email     = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  type      = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  description = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  street      = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  houseNumber = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  city        = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;

    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password,
      email: this.email,
      type: this.type,
      description: this.description,
      street: this.street,
      houseNumber: this.houseNumber,
      city: this.city
    });


    this.userService.getUser(this.userObj.userid)
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.success === false) {
        if (data.errcode) {     
          this.authService.logout();
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      } else {

        this.user = data.data[0];
        this.populateForm(this.user);        
      }
    });
  }

  populateForm(data): void {
    this.profileForm.patchValue({

      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
      email: data.email,
      type: data.type,
      description: data.description,
      street: data.street,
      houseNumber: data.houseNumber,
      city: data.city
    });
  }

  edition() {
  }
}
```

server code: **server/api.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router  = express.Router();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('./config');
var user = require('../routes/user.js');

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error connecting database, please check if MongoDB is running.');
    } else { console.log('Connected to database...');
    }
});
router.post('/login', user.login);
router.get('/user/:id', user.getuserDetails);
module.exports = router;
```

**routes/user.js** :

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
var User = require('../models/user');
var Address = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require('../server/config');

exports.getuserDetails = function(req, res, next){  
  User.find({_id:req.params.id}).exec(function(err, user){
      if(err){          
        res.status(400).json({
          success: false, message: 'Error processing request '+ err
        }); }
      res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      data: user
    });  
  });
}
```

I don't know what the error caused is. How to fix it?

the **exports.getuserDetails** method is not invoked

Comment: It is returning HTML instead of JSON

Comment: are you running your angular app on your express server? - otherwise you'll need to provide the full url - e..g `this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user/${userid}'` or whatever

Comment: Console.log your service map response and you will see that your server is not returning a proper json, probably due to an error somewhere

Comment: I introduced: `return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/user/${userid}', options).map((response: Response) =>  response.json()  );` and it still does not work